# how to distinguish between inline image and signature and other blank images in email Imap

Tags: c#, email, model-view-controller, imap, mailkit

I'm using Mailkit to fetch email from mailbox and save it to database to display in my MVC application.

I save html email as plain text in database, i can fetch attachments and save it in file system, but when there are inline images in email, i'm having issue as signatures and other blank images are too being saved as attachment in file system.

Is there a way to distinguish between inline attachment and signatures or other blank images?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i've got the same problem but i use ActiveUp, and i came to the solution of the problem, if you are interested on my solution let me know

Comment: i'm interested in more info on it please.

Comment: i used this: https://mailsystem.codeplex.com/ 
basically i've got a window service that check a mailbox folder, when it find some mail it read the html of the mail, the attachment and the images embedded in the text, after that it writes a post on an xwiki (i think you are not interested on this part) if you will consider the code of mine as solution or useful answer i'll give to you

Comment: is it possible to use your solution with mailkit? I'm too using console app for to find new email in mailbox folder. The bit i'm more interested is how to distinguish between signature and the real inline attachment not the attached attachment.

Comment: infact my problem was that the signature's images where not displayed at first time, because they were kept on others object, so when my service wrote the post on the xwiki it displayed missing images on the signatures (wich was very ugly) so basically with ActiveUp you can distinguish between different images,but i don't know mailkit sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter which IMAP library you use, none of them have a feature that will help you do what you want to do because it's a non-trivial problem to solve that you are going to need to use some ingenuity to solve.

What you can do is start with the `HtmlPreviewVisitor` sample from the [FAQ](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#HasAttachments) and modify it every-so-slightly to just split the attachments into 2 lists:

1. The list of actual attachments
2. The list of images *actually* referenced by the HTML (by walking the HTML and tracking which images are referenced)

code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Visits a MimeMessage and splits attachments into those that are
/// referenced by the HTML body vs regular attachments.
/// </summary>
class AttachmentVisitor : MimeVisitor
{
    List<MultipartRelated> stack = new List<MultipartRelated> ();
    List<MimeEntity> attachments = new List<MimeEntity> ();
    List<MimePart> embedded = new List<MimePart> ();
    bool foundBody;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new AttachmentVisitor.
    /// </summary>
    public AttachmentVisitor ()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The list of attachments that were in the MimeMessage.
    /// </summary>
    public IList<MimeEntity> Attachments {
        get { return attachments; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The list of embedded images that were in the MimeMessage.
    /// </summary>
    public IList<MimePart> EmbeddedImages {
        get { return embedded; }
    }

    protected override void VisitMultipartAlternative (MultipartAlternative alternative)
    {
        // walk the multipart/alternative children backwards from greatest level of faithfulness to the least faithful
        for (int i = alternative.Count - 1; i >= 0 && !foundBody; i--)
            alternative[i].Accept (this);
    }

    protected override void VisitMultipartRelated (MultipartRelated related)
    {
        var root = related.Root;

        // push this multipart/related onto our stack
        stack.Add (related);

        // visit the root document
        root.Accept (this);

        // pop this multipart/related off our stack
        stack.RemoveAt (stack.Count - 1);
    }

    // look up the image based on the img src url within our multipart/related stack
    bool TryGetImage (string url, out MimePart image)
    {
        UriKind kind;
        int index;
        Uri uri;

        if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString (url, UriKind.Absolute))
            kind = UriKind.Absolute;
        else if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString (url, UriKind.Relative))
            kind = UriKind.Relative;
        else
            kind = UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute;

        try {
            uri = new Uri (url, kind);
        } catch {
            image = null;
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = stack.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if ((index = stack[i].IndexOf (uri)) == -1)
                continue;

            image = stack[i][index] as MimePart;
            return image != null;
        }

        image = null;

        return false;
    }

    // called when an HTML tag is encountered
    void HtmlTagCallback (HtmlTagContext ctx, HtmlWriter htmlWriter)
    {
        if (ctx.TagId == HtmlTagId.Image && !ctx.IsEndTag && stack.Count > 0) {
            // search for the src= attribute
            foreach (var attribute in ctx.Attributes) {
                if (attribute.Id == HtmlAttributeId.Src) {
                    MimePart image;

                    if (!TryGetImage (attribute.Value, out image))
                        continue;

                    if (!embedded.Contains (image))
                        embedded.Add (image);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void VisitTextPart (TextPart entity)
    {
        TextConverter converter;

        if (foundBody) {
            // since we've already found the body, treat this as an
            // attachment
            attachments.Add (entity);
            return;
        }

        if (entity.IsHtml) {
            converter = new HtmlToHtml {
                HtmlTagCallback = HtmlTagCallback
            };

            converter.Convert (entity.Text);
        }

        foundBody = true;
    }

    protected override void VisitTnefPart (TnefPart entity)
    {
        // extract any attachments in the MS-TNEF part
        attachments.AddRange (entity.ExtractAttachments ());
    }

    protected override void VisitMessagePart (MessagePart entity)
    {
        // treat message/rfc822 parts as attachments
        attachments.Add (entity);
    }

    protected override void VisitMimePart (MimePart entity)
    {
        // realistically, if we've gotten this far, then we can treat
        // this as an attachment even if the IsAttachment property is
        // false.
        attachments.Add (entity);
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
var visitor = new AttachmentVisitor ();

message.Accept (visitor);

// Now you can use visitor.Attachments and visitor.EmbeddedImages
```

An even simpler, although less error-proof (sine it doesn't actually verify whether the image is referenced by the HTML), way of doing it is this:

```
var embeddedImages = message.BodyParts.OfType<MimePart> ().
    Where (x => x.ContentType.IsMimeType ("image", "*") &&
           x.ContentDisposition != null &&
           x.ContentDisposition.Disposition.Equals ("inline" StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Now that you have your list of `embeddedImages`, you'll have to figure out a way to determine if they are only used in the signature or used elsewhere in the HTML.

Most likely you'll have to analyze the HTML itself as well.

It is also probably worth noting that some HTML mail will reference images located on the web that are *not* embedded in the MIME of the message. If you want *these* images as well, you'll need to modify `TryGetImage` to fall back to downloading the image from the web if the code I provided fails to locate it within the MIME of the message.

For text/plain messages (which can't use images at all), the common convention to separate the signature from the rest of the message body is a line with only 2 dashes and a space: `--`.

From my limited experience with HTML messages that have signatures, they do not appear to follow a similar convention. Looking at a few of the HTML messages I receive from co-workers at Microsoft using Outlook, they appear to be within a `<table>` at the end of the message. However, this assumes that the message is not a reply. Once you start parsing message replies, this `<table>` ends up in the middle of the message somewhere because the original message being replied to is at the end.

Since everyone's signature is different as well, I'm not sure if this `<table>` similarity is an Outlook convention or if people are manually constructing their signatures and they are all just using tables out of coincidence (I've also only seen a few, most do not use signatures, so my sample size is very small).

Comment: thanks for that. i had tried from your documents. but couldnt get it working. shall try it again.

Comment: What you are trying to do is insanely difficult to do because unless you can find a fool-proof way of determining what HTML content makes up the signature, there's no way to figure out which images in the HTML are for the signature.

Comment: Wow, this is an awesome answer.

Comment: @jstedfast i have this issue where image is on web, i get content disposition as null, content-type as text\html for it. Can you point me out to a right direction for it

Comment: You'll have to parse the HTML and extract the URL for the image source and then download it using HttpWebRequest or something. You can use the MimeKit.Text.HtmlTokenizer to tokenize the HTML content or you could go with a simpler solution such as HtmlAgilityPack.

Answer (score 1):

Using https://mailsystem.codeplex.com/:

the class wich read the email:

```
class readMail:IDisposable
    {
        public Imap4Client client = new Imap4Client();
        public readMail(string mailServer, int port, bool ssl, string login, string password)
        {
            Pop3Client pop = new Pop3Client();
            if (ssl)
            {
                client.ConnectSsl(mailServer, port);
            }
            else
            client.Connect(mailServer, port);
            client.Login(login, password);
        }
        public IEnumerable<Message> GetAllMails(string mailBox)
        {
            IEnumerable<Message> ms = GetMails(mailBox, "ALL").Cast<Message>();
            return GetMails(mailBox, "ALL").Cast<Message>();
        }

        protected Imap4Client Client
        {
            get { return client ?? (client = new Imap4Client()); }
        }
        private MessageCollection GetMails(string mailBox, string searchPhrase)
        {
            try
            {
                MessageCollection messages = new MessageCollection();
                Mailbox mails = new Mailbox();
                mails = Client.SelectMailbox(mailBox);
                messages = mails.SearchParse(searchPhrase);
                return messages;
            }
            catch(Exception ecc)
            {

            }

        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

and then:

```
using (readMail read = new readMail("host.name.information", port, true, username, password) )
            {


                var emailList = read.GetAllMails(this.folderEmail);
                int k = 0;
                Mailbox bbb = read.client.SelectMailbox(this.folderEmail);
                int[] unseen = bbb.Search("UNSEEN");

                foreach (Message email in emailList)
                {

                  /// Contains all parts for which no Content-Disposition header was found. Disposition is left to the final agent.
                  MimePartCollection im1= email.UnknownDispositionMimeParts;
                  //Collection containing embedded MIME parts of the message (included text parts)
                  EmbeddedObjectCollection im2 = email.EmbeddedObjects;
                  //Collection containing attachments of the message.
                  AttachmentCollection attach=email.Attachments;
               }
            }
```

in my case all the signature's images were in UnknownDispositionMimeParts, but this could be a specific case (different email client and so on)..so for what i know i didn't find any library that separate embedded images from contextual images to signature images

Comment: How does this distinguish between signature images and other images referenced by the HTML?

Comment: you'll have to figure out a way to determine if they are only used in the signature or used elsewhere in the HTML.

Comment: That's what the question is, though, so your answer doesn't answer it at all.

Comment: ops i just copied it from your answer, so not even your answer doesn't answer it at all :)

Comment: Which is why I explained how to walk the HTML to get him at least *started* :)

Comment: we both know that you are right :D that's why i will upvote your question (i've updated mine to say that in my case i catch all the signature images in UnknownDispositionMimeParts but it was probably a special case)